# Callback functions in php and exceptions

Tags: php, callback

Currently I'm reading [php's manual about callback functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and found interesting note:

> Callbacks registered with functions such as call_user_func() and call_user_func_array() will not be called **if there is an uncaught exception thrown in a previous callback**.

It's obvious that script run will be interrupted in case of uncaught exception. So, why did authors of php manual additionally write that about call_user_func? Or I misunderstood the statement?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to me more a reminder than part of the doc. All uncaught exceptions are fatal in php, unless they were talking about call_user_func() borking even if you have set a **handler** (with set_exception_handler) instead of a catch, which sounds like something a lawyer would do..

Comment: can you please explain? your answer is confusing